# String multiplication idiom in apex?

Tags: apex

Does apex include any programming idioms to quickly and clearly initialise or pad strings with a specific character, for example 'string multiplication' such as `'-'*40` to easily create a rule, or `'.'*(size-str.length()` to pad to length?

I new to apex, though experienced developer; I want to produce a quick and simple bar graph of a specific dataset to highlight any anomalies.  This code will render a bar-graph to the logs, seems very 'old school', surely there is better way to do this in apex?  I want something that is clear and concise. Surely there is a way to do without the nested loop in the produce bar graph part of the code?

```
// retrieve distribution data
Integer[] distribution = new Integer[100];
for(Integer i=0; i<1000 ; i++) {
    // the real data actual comes from elsewhere;
    // this just simulates it with random numbers for this example.
    Integer num = (math.random() * 100).intValue();
    System.assert(num >= 0 && num < 100, 'Value out of expected range : ' + num);
    if (distribution[num] == null) {
        distribution[num] = 1;
    } else {
        distribution[num]++;
    }
}

// produce bar graph
String barGraph = '\n';
for(Integer num=0; num<100 ; num++) {
    barGraph += '' + num + ') ';
    // Surely there is better way to do this bit?
    for(integer i=0 ; i<distribution[num] ; i++) { barGraph += '.'; }
    barGraph += '\n';
}
System.Debug( barGraph );
```

Comment: can rightPad help you? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm

Comment: So you're rendering a bar graph in the debug log, eh? Is this data ever displayed on a Visualforce page / Lightning component? If so, you may consider using [the charting built in to Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_example.htm) or a javascript library like D3.js or chart.js.

Comment: @DerekF in this case the code will be used in testing only, it is not part of the core functional requirements, so the test logs will be fine for this output.  If you want to suggest wider solution for others to benefit go right ahead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use String.Repeat

> String.repeat Returns the current String repeated the specified number
>   of times.

```
String s1 = 'SFDC';
String s2 = 
   s1.repeat(2);
System.assertEquals(
   'SFDCSFDC', s2);
```

Also if you want a delimiter in between you can also specify that.

```
String s1 = 'SFDC';
String s2 = 
   s1.repeat('-', 2);
System.assertEquals(
   'SFDC-SFDC', s2);
```

Src : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_repeat

Answer (score 6):

Using the comment by [@kurunve](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/18189/kurunve) for direction, and for the benefit of others, this is the improved code using [rightPad](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#rightPad).

```
// single line rule.
System.Debug( ''.rightPad(40, '-' ));
// produce bar graph
String barGraph = '\n';
for(Integer num=0; num<100 ; num++) {
    barGraph += '' + num + ') '.rightPad(distribution[num], '+') + '\n';
}
System.Debug( barGraph );
// produce double line rule.
System.Debug( ''.rightPad(40, '=' ));
```

Comment: Another way would be to use String.repeat . https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_repeat

Comment: @pranay just add that as an answer. Much more correct for this use case and what I would have answered. But since you already mentioned it.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal,  I'm happy to accept a better answer, if you want to post an answer using that approach.

Comment: @MartinofHessle Which you now can. :)